# Java won't run because there a break statement outside a loop, but I have it inside a loop

Tags: java, loops, applet, return

I'm having two weird errors

New error is when i tell java to draw a string that displays the coordinateness of x and y, It doesn't.

```
public void paint (Graphics g)
{
    super.paint (g);

   //System.out.println ("Boolean: " + this.closeDoors);


    g.drawString("("+x+","+y+")",x,y);
}
```

Link to my program if you to compile it.
http://hotfile.com/dl/107032853/c81d927/Pigment.java.html

This is my complete program

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Graphics;

/**
 *
 * @author George Beazer
 */
public class Pigment extends JApplet 
{
    boolean closeDoors;
    private int x = 0;
    private int y = 0;


    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
            Pigment stuff = new Pigment();
    }
    public Pigment()

    {

        setBackground (Color.blue);
    }

    @Override
    public void init()
    {
         setLayout(new FlowLayout());
         addMouseListener(new MyMouseListener());
    }
    @Override
    public void paint (Graphics g)
    {
        super.paint (g);

       //System.out.println ("Boolean: " + this.closeDoors);


        g.drawString("("+x+","+y+")",x,y);
         if (x > 35)

            {
                            g.drawLine (35, 50, 570, 50);
                g.drawLine (35, 50, 250, 0);
                g.drawLine (250, 0, 570, 50);
                g.drawRect (50, 50, 500, 350);
                g.fillRect (100, 75, 80, 80);
                g.fillRect (400, 75, 80, 80);
                g.fillRect (240, 200, 125, 200);


            }

        else
            {        
            g.drawLine (35, 50, 570, 50);
            g.drawLine (35, 50, 250, 0);
            g.drawLine (250, 0, 570, 50);
            g.drawLine (180, 120, 100, 120);
            g.drawLine (400, 120, 480, 120);
            g.drawLine (140, 75, 140, 160);
            g.drawLine (450, 75, 450, 160);
            g.drawRect (50, 50, 500, 350);
            g.drawRect (100, 75, 80, 80);
            g.drawRect (400, 75, 80, 80);
            g.drawRect (240, 200, 125, 200);
            g.drawOval (330,280, 20, 20);
            }


    }
    private class MyMouseListener implements MouseListener
    {
        public void mouseClicked (MouseEvent e)
        {
            x = e.getX();
            y = e.getY();

        }

        public void mouseEntered (MouseEvent e)
        {


        }
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){}
        public void mousePressed (MouseEvent e){

        }
        public void mouseReleased (MouseEvent e){}

    }

}
```

Comment: I might be missing something but I can't see a single loop in your code sample.

Comment: Where is you loop? You only have a break which is in an IF statement.

Comment: You should accept correct answers to your previous questions.

Comment: You really need to go and click the CheckMark on the answers that are "Accepted" on your previous questions, people are going to stop answering you if you don't.

Comment: Also hotfile.com is a **TERRIBLE** place to expect people to download code from. It is a pay site and hideous to deal with if you don't have a subscription. Consider something like the Gist feature of github.com in the future.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With regards to your first question, the reason that you're getting a compiler error here:

```
if (x > 35)
{
    g.drawLine (35, 50, 570, 50);
    g.drawLine (35, 50, 250, 0);

    repaint();
    break;  
}
```

Is that this `break` statement is not actually in a loop.  In Java, you can break out of `while`, `for`, `do...while`, and `switch` statements, but not `if` statements.  There's not a particularly good reason for this - it's mainly historical - but the compiler does indeed enforce it.

Of the three aforementioned control structures, `for`, `while`, and `do...while` are referred to as loops because they execute code potentially many times.  The `break` statement in this case is a way of saying "please abort execution of the current loop; I don't want to run it any more."  Its opposite is `continue`, which means "please go to the next iteration of this loop."

The reason you can break out of a `switch` is because Java's `switch` statement is based on the C programming language's version of `switch` in which labels are "fall-through."  In this context, `break` means "I have finished executing all of the code I want to execute in this particular label; please get me out of this statement."  Interestingly, you can `break` out of a `switch`, but you can't `continue`.

However, you cannot `break` out of an `if` statement.  There is no high-level reason for this, and in fact the language designers could just as easily have allowed this behavior to mean "stop executing this part of the `if` statement."  I think the reason they opted not to do this is that `if` statements have a sort of "implicit `break`" at the end of each handler.  For example, if you write

```
if (condition()) {
    // A
} else {
    // B
}
// C
```

Then after executing `A`, the control flow will immediately jump you to `C`, rather than falling through to the `else` handler.

If you want to simulate a `break` out of of the middle of an `if` statement, you could do something like this:

```
if (condition()) {
     // code

     if (someOtherCondition()) {
          // more code
     }
}
```

The idea here is that you run the `if` statement for some time, then decide using a *second* `if` statement whether or not to run the rest of the code in the loop.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I din see your message before :)

Comment: Yes i understand that, but how do I make the repaint(); run once?>

Comment: @user516805- I think the issue is that you're calling `repaint` within `paint`, which means that every time the window is painted, it will get painted again.  Removing that line should fix this problem.

Comment: @user516805: you're calling repaint within paint... could that be the issue? – nico 6 mins ago
I'm calling repaint withing pain because i painted something, then i change the paint and I want it to show the paint i made changes to.

Comment: I'm calling repaint withing pain because i painted something, then i change the paint and I want it to show the paint i made changes to.

Comment: @user516805- I understand that, but I don't think that's the place to issue the repaint.  If you changed something in your program that causes the display to need to be updated, call `repaint` from that part of the code.  The actual implementation of `paint` will make the changes show up to the panel once the method returns, and so you don't need to indicate to Java that it needs to be updated once more.

Comment: @user516805: from the manual entry for `repaint`: `If this component is a lightweight component, this method causes a call to this component's paint method as soon as possible.`. So when in `paint` you call `repaint` that in turns calls `paint` and so on and so on...

Answer (score 5):

`if (x > 35) {...}` is **not** a loop it is a statement.

`for (int x = 0; x <= 35; x++) {...}` is a loop.

`while( x <= 35 ) {...}` is a loop.

`do {...} while ( x <= 35 )` is a loop.

Take the `repaint()` call out it is redundant.

*You really need to go and click the CheckMark on the answers that are "Accepted" on your previous questions, people are going to stop answering you if you don't*.

Comment: Then how do stop repain(); from paint over and over again.

Comment: @user516805: you're calling `repaint` within `paint`... could that be the issue?

Comment: I'm calling repaint withing pain because i painted something, then i change the paint and I want it to show the paint i made changes to.

Answer (score 1):

> Java won't run because there a break statement outside a loop, but I have it inside a loop.

No, you have it inside an `if` statement, which is not a loop. Even if it worked, `break` would be useless there, the statement will be executed only once.

Answer (score 0):

An if-else block is not a loop, that is your issue here.  Your second error might be because x and y are not declared, at least not in the code you showed us.

Comment: I defined the x and y coordinateness as     private int x = 0;
    private int y = 0;.

Answer (score 0):

at your line 59, there is **break** statement in the **IF** block. which doesn't make sense. Remove it and your program is good to go.

Comment: How do you make the repaint(); method run once.

Comment: what do you mean **for once**. is it your program requirement? if yes then you gotta reconsider your design. is it your debugging requirement? then put the breakpoint on IF condition. It will stop on every execution. you can let it execute first time and can debug second time.

Comment: Java repaint is in loop, how do i make it run once.

Comment: I can't see any **loop** in your program. perhaps you are calling it from some other class. I don't know. the **worst case** solution would be in your class, -- private static int counter = 0; .. and then where you are doing the repain(); .. do it this way .. if (counter == 0){repaint(); counter++;} --- but this isn't "right" solution. just put it this way to help you out

Comment: I have another g.drawString("("+x+","+y+")",x,y); is somehow hiding it's self in behind of the object i painted. How do i make g.drawString("("+x+","+y+")",x,y); appear in front or move it.

Comment: possibly change of its cordinates. could you share your **full progra**?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks alee for your suggestion.

I move repaint(); method from the paint class to MyMouseListener class. That work perfectly and Java was repainting a image constantly,

Chapter 14 Java Programming Challenge number 2.

Write an applet that draws the house shown on the left in figure 14-32. When the user clicks

on the door or windows, they should close. The figure on the right shows the house with its

door and windows closed.

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.Graphics;

/**
 *
 * @author George Beazer
 */
public class Pigment extends JApplet 
{
    public int x = 0;
    public int y = 0;


    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
    }
    public Pigment()

    {
        setBackground (Color.blue);
    }

    @Override
    public void init()
    {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        addMouseListener(new MyMouseListener());
    }
    @Override
    public void paint (Graphics g)
    {
        super.paint (g);

        //System.out.println ("Boolean: " + this.closeDoors);




        if (x > 100 && x < 175 && y < 155 && y > 75)
            {
                g.drawLine (35, 50, 570, 50);
                g.drawLine (35, 50, 250, 0);
                g.drawLine (250, 0, 570, 50);
                g.drawLine (180, 120, 100, 120);
                g.drawLine (400, 120, 480, 120);
                g.drawLine (140, 75, 140, 154);
                g.drawLine (440, 75, 440, 154);
                g.drawRect (50, 50, 500, 350);
                g.drawRect (100, 75, 80, 80);
                g.drawRect (400, 75, 80, 80);
                g.drawRect (240, 200, 125, 200);
                g.drawOval (330,280, 20, 20);
            }
        else if (x > 400 && x < 475 && y < 155 && y > 75)
            {
                g.drawLine (35, 50, 570, 50);
                g.drawLine (35, 50, 250, 0);
                g.drawLine (250, 0, 570, 50);
                g.drawLine (180, 120, 100, 120);
                g.drawLine (400, 120, 480, 120);
                g.drawLine (140, 75, 140, 154);
                g.drawLine (440, 75, 440, 154);
                g.drawRect (50, 50, 500, 350);
                g.drawRect (100, 75, 80, 80);
                g.drawRect (400, 75, 80, 80);
                g.drawRect (240, 200, 125, 200);
                g.drawOval (330,280, 20, 20);
            }

        else if (x > 240 && x < 360 && y < 400 && y > 200)
            {
                g.drawLine (35, 50, 570, 50);
                g.drawLine (35, 50, 250, 0);
                g.drawLine (250, 0, 570, 50);
                g.drawLine (180, 120, 100, 120);
                g.drawLine (400, 120, 480, 120);
                g.drawLine (140, 75, 140, 154);
                g.drawLine (440, 75, 440, 154);
                g.drawRect (50, 50, 500, 350);
                g.drawRect (100, 75, 80, 80);
                g.drawRect (400, 75, 80, 80);
                g.drawRect (240, 200, 125, 200);
                g.drawOval (330,280, 20, 20);
            }
        else
            {        
                g.drawLine (35, 50, 570, 50);
                g.drawLine (35, 50, 250, 0);
                g.drawLine (250, 0, 570, 50);
                g.drawRect (50, 50, 500, 350);
                g.fillRect (100, 75, 80, 80);
                g.fillRect (400, 75, 80, 80);
                g.fillRect (240, 200, 125, 200);
            }

    }

    private class MyMouseListener implements MouseListener
    {

        public void mouseEntered (MouseEvent e)
        {
        }
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)
        {       
        }
        public void mousePressed (MouseEvent e)

        {
        }
        public void mouseReleased (MouseEvent e){}

        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
        {
            x = e.getX();
            y = e.getY();
            showStatus( "Mouse at (" + x + "," + y + ")" );
            repaint();
        }       
    }
}
```

You can close this thread.